# How to: MSAL and ASP.NET MVC Web App Config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have gone through a ton of examples and samples on how to use `MSAL` in `ASP.NET` `MVC 5`, but I cannot seem to get it right.

Things I am confused on:

- How can I get a graph token during logon and save it to my database?
- Can you even use `MSAL` alone for authentication?

Comment: Man, I am exactly right there with you. I have an MVC app hosted in Azure and I created a mobile app that uses MSAL to retrieve the identity and access tokens for a user. But I see no examples of how to then use those tokens to authenticate to the MVC / WebAPI apps. I'm assuming I need to get a bearer token that the application will respect but I don't know how to do that so I am stuck. Hope you get an answer to your question because it will help me, as well!

Comment: Well, since it doesn't look like we're gonna get any help from the ADAL team (MSAL), I will throw this out there. They have put together some interesting tutorials that may get us there. See https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2 and maybe https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/. The first one goes into deploying the needed pieces in Azure, which, to me, is really the biggest knowledge hole. Microsoft uses the terms API, Service, and App so often that their meanings get obfuscated. Good luck!

Comment: Lastly, take a look at this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal